# How to connect C# .NET application to the AWS RDS Oracle account? (and SQL Developer)

Tags: c#, oracle, amazon-web-services, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

Problem is simple. I have all necessary credentials from AWS console
- DB name
- Username
- password
- Endpoint
- Port
- Pulicity Accessible
...

But standard connection way (using using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;) to the database is not working.

The same is with Oracle Developer (IDE for SQL commands). I do not know how can I connect to the RDS.

Do you have some ideas? Or experience?

Comment: `But standard connection way (using using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;) to the database is not working.`? Add details and code, exceptions,errors...

Comment: Is the server you are running Oracle Developer within same VPC and having security groups open to access the RDS instance?

Comment: @Ashan - probably you have true. But all activities:
- creation DB instance
- creation Security Group 
has been created on the same PC (it means that VPC is generated automatically for this PC).

Is there way how to open RDS for public? Do you have some manual?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you followed this guide to connect to the Oracle DB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.Oracle.html

This guide provides this example:

```
PROMPT>sqlplus 'mydbusr@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=endpoint DNS name) (PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))'>
```

You can store this connection descriptor in a tnsnames.ora and later use it in sqldeveloper.

tnsnames.ora example:

```
orcl = 
(DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS=
    (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=endpoint DNS name) (PORT=1521)
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA=
    (SID=ORCL)
  )
)
```

(OK, this is bad habit from Amazon. Do not use "SID" use "SERVICE_NAME" instead!)

You can also extract the information from the connect descriptor and use basic connection configuration in SQLDeveloper.

BTW: Do you have an error message for us?